# multiple dev environments other than tenants

Tags: azure, azure-sphere

So lets say I want to stage my firmware to a select group of devices before I push my new firmware into production. I still want to push to stage via OTA. Something akin to the spheres dev and retail os feeds.  Can I set this up for my organization within the same tenant, or do I need to have each environment their own tenant to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that on the same Azure Sphere Tenant - if you use different device groups where each device group has feeds for production and dev accordingly.

For example you can create one device group for the devices in your test lab and another for devices in the retail channel. Devices in the test lab group receive the test application feed, and the devices in the retail group receive the production application feed.

**Note:** The feeds you create depend on one of the two different system software feeds **Retail Azure Sphere OS** or **Retail Evaluation Azure Sphere OS**.